# How to offset in fseek from current position

Tags: c, string, file, fseek

I somehow cannot ofset from `SEEK_CUR`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("txt", "w+b");
    if(!fp)
        return 1;
    
    fprintf(fp, "20");
    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    fprintf(fp, "19");

    long size = ftell(fp) + 1;
    rewind(fp);
    char * buf = malloc(size+1);
    buf = memset(buf, 0, size+1); //should I really do this? becuase, after the "20" there will be \0 so I won't see the rest (` 19`)
    fread(buf, sizeof(char), size, fp);
    printf("%s\n",buf);

}
```

*output*:

```
20
```

but should be `20 19`, which I cannot `fread()` from that file, why?

Comment: > *Should I use null character to end a string in c*  No, it's just a recent fad that is likely to be short-lived.

Comment: @Kaz but I am still getting garbage at the end. So how should I get rid of it *without* null character?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a moving target. The question has been edited to ask about a completely different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you write "20" to the file, then skip one byte/character ahead in the file, then write "19" to the file. The skipped character needs to be written as some value... and that value is `\0`.

So you read "20\019" from the file into a buf initialized to seven `\0` bytes by the `memset` call. `buf` now contains `"20\019\0\0"`.

`printf("%s\n", buf)` prints `buf` as a NUL terminated string, i.e. until the first NUL byte appears. That NUL byte comes immediately after the "20", so it only prints "20".

If you were to hexdump the buffer with a hexdump function (to be written as an exercise)

```
hexdump(buf, size);
```

it would print something like

```
0000  32 30 00 31 39 00      -                     20.19.
```

Comment: Ok, so how should I fix it? I have commented out the `memset` (which is setting the '\0'), but that did not helped. How should I fix my code?

Comment: If you do not want to interpret `buf` as a NUL terminated string, do not use functions which interpret character arrays as NUL terminated strings. E.g. write your own `void hexdump(void *buf, size_t size)` function to print the content of `buf`.

Comment: @give_me_one: use `fputc(' ', fp);` to write a space character instead of fseeking over the NUL -- if you want to write a character to a file, you need to actually write it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `buf` is not null-terminated. The array is exactly sized to hold the content of the text file, without any null termination.

Try

```
char buf[size+1] = "";   /* initialize buf to all zeros, with room for null terminator */
```

A string literal object is already null-terminated, so for most purposes, this is superfluous:

```
char *str = "abc\0";
```

The string is now terminated by two nulls, which could be useful in some special circumstances. Microsoft came up with a data format used in the Windows Registry for storing a list of strings. Each string in the list is null-terminated, and then one more null byte unambiguously terminates the entire list.  We could declare such a thing in C as:

```
char *windows_reg_style_list = "how\0now\0brown\cow\0";
```

To ordinary string processing in C, `"abc\0"` looks the same as `"abc"`: it's as string of length 3, and likewise the above datum looks like the string `"how"`.

There is, I think, only one situation in which the `"..."` notation in C source code will not produce a null terminated string. And that is when it is used as the initializer for an array which is exactly sized for that number of characters:

```
char no_null_term[4] = "abcd";
```

If we make it `[5]` it will be null terminated, and `[3]` would be erroneous since the array is too small to hold `abcd`. The `[4]` is allowed as a special case for initializing arrays that don't behave like null-terminated strings.

Also note that to use `ftell`, the stream has to be binary: `fopen(..., "w+b")`. So that is to say, `ftell` is not required to return a value that corresponds to the number of characters written to the text stream.

Comment: See the edits, there are some mis-behaving with that fseek